# Randomly selecting data from different columns into one column without duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, code

I have four columns of students. There is 1000 students in each column. The same students are in each of the four columns. I need to randomly select one student from each column to make groups of four.  But how can I do this so the same student isn't listed twice in the same group?

Comment: Can you handle VBA macro? Since your issue can be easily solved using a Macro. Also tell me are you want to extract Four names in other Column or wanna to identify only like by highlight them?

Comment: Yes I think I can handle VBA macro.  And yes I am wanting to extract four names, (1 from column A, 1 from column B, 1 from column C, 1 from Column D and then put all four names into column E

Comment: Are you saying that there are 1000 students, and they are all listed four times, but in different orders? Or are you saying that you have between 1001 and 3999 students, divided into four overlapping groups?

Comment: @Karen,, did you want to extract all duplicates from Four Columns? Like,, Sam in all 4 Cols but in different rows !!

Comment: If it's 4 identical columns of names, it would probably be easier just to extract all names from a single column. Is there any reason for it being four? Is the result expected to be 250 groups, or 1000 groups, with the same students 4 times, but in different configurations?

Comment: @Scott I have about 1600 unique students so they will be divided into four overlapping groups

Comment: @Christofer Weber the four columns are not identical there are about 1600 unique students across the four columns

Comment: @Rajesh I want to extract 1 name from each column and put the four names into column E.  They are then Group 1.  But of the four names taken from each column the same student can't be listed twice.

Comment: The only reasonable way this would work in my mind, is using a VBA Macro to take a random name from col 1, then remove/disable that name from all columns (if it exists), then repeat for col 2-4. And then print the four names in the new column. Depending on how the names are distributed however, this could possibly end up with depleting one column before the others. But writing a function to prevent that is a whole different issue. If removing them is an issue, copy the columns first, and use the copies as helpers, or double check duplicates (much slower).